# ld undefined symbols for architecture when creating .dylib on Mac OS-X 10.10 Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: macos, xcode6, llvm, osx-yosemite

I got this on Mac OS-X 10.10 with Xcode 6.3.1

```
Undefined symbols for architecture :
  "start", referenced from:
    implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer in the `ld man` page.
There is no `ld -dynamic` any more instead use `ld -dylib`. I hope this helps maybe someone.

**RTFM**